# Which method is called if I reopen a Fragment?

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, refresh

I have the following problem:

I have three fragments that I can switch through swiping. The first contains images that are regularly made visible and invisible by an external method. However, I see the change in the visibility of the images only when I leave the fragment by swiping and then swipe back again.

Therefore, the question is which method is called when rewinding back, so that I can call this explicitly if the fragment is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help when you back on the fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```